# How to build iOS Swift Alarm App with background Task

Tags: ios, swift, background, alarm

Im facing troubles with an app im working on.

I already have an android app that is running like that:

A background task i checking every 30 seconds an api to check if there is something going on my server.
When there is a result an alarm will come up and plays an mp3 and then shows an full screen activity with text and buttons.
The mp3 will be repeated for 5 minutes or when the user clicks on a button and replies to the alarm.
The mp3 is also played even if the pohone settings are on mute.

I also have an Setting inside the app where you can choose to mute the sound and only show the activity.

I need to have the same behaviour in my ios app but have no idea how to handle it in Swift.
The background task itself is also terminated after 30 seconds.

Comment: Polling is not going to work (and is a bad approach anyway). You should send a push notification when there is an event.  You can send a silent push notification and use that to trigger a series of local notifications

Comment: Ok seems like an good approach but is it possible to make these local notifications play a sound even if the generel settings are mute? 
This is the most important feature of the app

Comment: @AndreFritzsche no it's not possible, Apple restricts these to 30s in length and they will not make a sound when in silent mode, essentially making an Alarm impossible to implement on iOS without resorting to various hacks that may or may not get through app store review.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you know how you could do that and how long it will take for you? :) Im stuck with this!